# Connect to SQL Server instance running on playwithdocker with a local Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, docker, ssms, sql-server-linux

I'm able to run a SQL Server (for linux) instance in playwith docker

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Password_01!" -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname ciccio  -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

and issue some commands from the terminal

```
docker exec -it sql1 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S ciccio -U sa -P Password_01!
```

However, I can't to connect to this instance from my local Management Studio.

Does anyone know how to do this? What check to see if the ports are open or the connection is reachable?

I've tried with the following address combinations:

`http://ip172-18-0-43-bkarle1t0o8g00cjuvdg-1433.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com
http://ip172-18-0-43-bkarle1t0o8g00cjuvdg-1433.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com,1433
ip172-18-0-43-bkarle1t0o8g00cjuvdg-1433.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com
ip172-18-0-43-bkarle1t0o8g00cjuvdg-1433.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com,1433`

the `ip172-18-0-43-bkarle1t0o8g00cjuvdg-1433.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com` are the urls provided from playwithdocker when the service is up and running